# How to convert JavaScript object to to table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object.

```
{"SI":{"0":"1","1":""},"Description of Goods":{"0":"LTD","1":"TET"},"HSN/SAC":{"0":"38220090","1":""},"MRP/ Marginal":{"0":"849.00/NO","1":""},"Quantity":{"0":"30 NO 30 NO","1":""},"Rate":{"0":"470.00","1":""},"per":{"0":"NO","1":""},"Amount":{"0":"14,100.00","1":"846.00 "}}
```

I want to convert it into

```
[{Amount: "14,100.00",Description of Goods: "LTD",HSN/SAC: "38220090",MRP/ Marginal:"849.00/NO",Quantity: "30 NO 30 NO",Rate: "470.00",SI: "1",per: "NO"} ,{Amount: "",Description of Goods: "TET",HSN/SAC: "",MRP/ Marginal:"",Quantity: "",Rate: "",SI: "1",per: "",Amount : "846.00 "}]
```

Here in object there are 2 rows but It can be more.

Comment: This doesn't seem too difficult. What have you tried so far? [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for ... of` with `Object.entries(obj)` as follows:

```js
let oOld = {"SI":{"0":"1","1":""},"Description of Goods":{"0":"LTD","1":"TET"},"HSN/SAC":{"0":"38220090","1":""},"MRP/ Marginal":{"0":"849.00/NO","1":""},"Quantity":{"0":"30 NO 30 NO","1":""},"Rate":{"0":"470.00","1":""},"per":{"0":"NO","1":""},"Amount":{"0":"14,100.00","1":"846.00 "}};
let oNew = [];
for(let [key,value] of Object.entries(oOld)) {
    for(let [k,v] of Object.entries(value)) {
        if( !oNew[+k] ) {
            oNew.push({});
        }
        oNew[+k][key] = v;
    }
}
console.log( oNew );
```

Alternatively, you can use the `.map()` and `.reduce()` methods as follows:

```js
let oOld = {"SI":{"0":"1","1":""},"Description of Goods":{"0":"LTD","1":"TET"},"HSN/SAC":{"0":"38220090","1":""},"MRP/ Marginal":{"0":"849.00/NO","1":""},"Quantity":{"0":"30 NO 30 NO","1":""},"Rate":{"0":"470.00","1":""},"per":{"0":"NO","1":""},"Amount":{"0":"14,100.00","1":"846.00 "}};

let oNew = Object.entries(oOld).map(([key,value]) => ([key,Object.entries(value)])).map(([key,value]) => value.map(val => ({[key]:val[1]}))).reduce((acc,val) => val.map((v,i) => (acc[i] || acc.push([])) && acc[i].concat(v)), []).map(a => a.reduce((acc,val) => Object.assign(acc,val),{}));

console.log( oNew );
```